# Rank functions in SQL

Tags: sql

My task is to figure out how many times the members have visited
the libary at the current visit dates. I have the following 
example records for **one member**. For example, on 10/1/2000 
(visit_id = 55353) this member visited the libary first time ever,
so he has 0 visit prior on 10/1/2000. Then on 12/15/2000 (visit_id = 12355)
this member visited the library again, now he has 1 visit prior to 12/15/2012.
Again this member visited the library on 01/01/2002 (visit_id = 52524) and 
now he has 2 visits prior to 01/01/2002.Now move on to prior to his latest 
visit 12/12/2009 (visit_id = 45254) this member has 9 visits to the library.

```
Member_ID   Date_Visit  Visit_id
12345       2000-10-01  55353
12345       2000-12-15  12355
12345       2002-01-01  52524
12345       2002-01-02  62558
12345       2003-05-30  22287
12345       2003-08-12  82552
12345       2003-09-12  12563
12345       2005-11-25  78785
12345       2008-12-25  98212
12345       2009-12-12  45254
```

I have a script below using rank function but i am stuck at the first
visit and the last visit. Please note, this is just **one member** for this
demonstration. Actual data includes **many members**.

```
SELECT
DATE_VISIT,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY DATE_VISIT) AS Rank
FROM RANKS

DATE_VISIT  Rank
2000-10-01  1
2000-12-15  2
2002-01-01  3
2002-01-02  4
2003-05-30  5
2003-08-12  6
2003-09-12  7
2005-11-25  8
2008-12-25  9
2009-12-12  10
```

I would like my output like this:

```
DATE_VISIT  Rank
2000-10-01  0
2000-12-15  1
2002-01-01  2
2002-01-02  3
2003-05-30  4
2003-08-12  5
2003-09-12  6
2005-11-25  7
2008-12-25  8
2009-12-12  9
```

Could anyone please take a look and help? Are there other functions, case statments or 
modify the rank function to make it work?

Comment: . . You must be very tired.  Subtracting "1" from a calculation is not generally considered a hard problem.  You got the hard part, which is understanding the `rank` function.

Comment: Thanks. I did not plan to subtract 1 from a calculation. Just the syntax that gave me the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried just subtracting 1?

```
SELECT
DATE_VISIT,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY DATE_VISIT) -1  AS Rank
FROM RANKS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
  Date_Visit,
  Rank - 1
From (    
  Select
    Date_Visit,
    Rank() Over (Partition By Member_Id Order By Date_Visit) AS Rank
   From
     Ranks
  ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following, also use different alias for rank column

```
SELECT DATE_VISIT, (Rnk - 1) NewRnk FROM (
SELECT
DATE_VISIT,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY DATE_VISIT) AS Rnk
FROM RANKS
)
```